# how to share 2 compute nodes to 1 vm in openstack?

Tags: openstack

is it possible to share resources of other compute nodes in open-stack.i mean is there anyway that Vm running on compute1 node will use the resources of compute2 , if yes how it is possible? or is there anyway to use or combine two servers resource to make them 1 server? Is sharing is possible between servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with OpenStack.

OpenStack relies on a [hypervisor](https://docs.openstack.org/ocata/config-reference/compute/hypervisors.html) such as KVM, Xen or Hyper-V to manage the virtual machines.  As far as I am aware none of the supported hypervisors allow you to "stitch together" CPU and memory resources on multiple compute nodes to form a virtual machine.

If you are looking for a technology that can stitch together compute nodes, one possibility is [ScaleMP's "vSMP ServerONE" product](https://www.scalemp.com/products/vsmp-serverone/).  As the "blurb" says:

> With vSMP ServerONE, multiple servers appear to the operating system, applications, administrators, developers or users as a single entity, running only one copy of the operating system. Each CPU in the aggregated system has access to all of the memory, enabling applications to scale using thread-parallel execution such as OpenMP.

There is a catch though.  Memory sharing in vSMP works by using virtual memory hardware to (effectively) swap virtual pages between different servers:

- This requires high speed networking.  (The faster the better.)
- If you have a workload where the threads and processes don't have good memory locality, performance will suffer.  It is a bit like classical virtual memory thrashing.

See also:

- Wikipedia: [Comparison of platform virtualization software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_platform_virtualization_software)